# Nginx domain path issue

Tags: nginx

I have the following domain fairgrounds.mohave.gov.  If the users just type fairgrounds.mohave.gov I would like it to go to the following path:

https://fairgrounds.mohave.gov/parks/fairgrounds/

otherwise, just behave like normal.  Here is the following configuration:

```
server {
            listen 80;
    #       listen 443;
            server_name fairgrounds.mohave.gov;
    #       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    #       return 301 https://fairgrounds.mohave.gov/parks/fairgrounds/;
            return 301 https://$host/$request_uri;
    }


server {
            listen 443 ssl http2;
            server_name fairgrounds.mohave.gov;

            root /var/www/parks2;

            index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

            location / {
                    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

                    add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
                    add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must_revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
                    if_modified_since off;
                    expires off;
                    etag off;
            }

    }
```

I've tried several approaches showing the commented-out section in the sample above, but they don't seem to work.  Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to externally redirect `/` to `/parks/fairgrounds/` in the second `server` block.

Try:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;

    ...

    location = / {
        return 301 /parks/fairgrounds/;
    }    
    location / {
        ...
    }
}
```

The first `location` block only matches `/` and externally redirects visitors to `https://example.com/parks/fairgrounds/`. The second `location` block is your existing location block, and handles everything else. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.